# Why do I get no output when getting a block from a blockchain?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

Basically I am running these commands:

```
var blocknumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
var transaction = await web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(blocknumber, 0)
console.log(transaction)
```

But transaction never gets any output, regardless of the iterator. Block number is fetched properly, I can also get the block via web3.eth.getBlock(blocknumber), but the transactions cannot be fetched for some reason.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code you want friend:

```
async function GetTransactions(){
    latestBlock=await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
    Block =await web3.eth.getBlock(latestBlock)

    Block.transactions.forEach(async(transactionAddress) => {
        let t=await web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionAddress)
        console.log(t)
    })
}
GetTransactions()
```

This will give Transactions of the Latest Block.

Also, Instade of `latestBlock`, you can pass any `Block Number` to get its all transactions details.
A Block have ~10 Transactions Addressess, and by `web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionAddress)` you can get that transactions details.

Ref: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems the provider simply does not allow this method.

> Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "\n403 Forbidden